# How do you execute external programs?

Tags: pascal

I'm working with [SCAR](http://freddy1990.com/index.php?page=product&name=scar), A pascal IDE that is used to make macros for runescape. In my program I need to execute an external .py I made. I've searched everywhere and cannot find a working solution.
Are there are functions that will do what I'm asking?

Edit: What I mean is run, just like the program would if you were to double-click on it.

Comment: Functions in one language that will execute (or in this case, interpret), are extremely rare, I'd imagine. If you could convert the Python in to Pascal it would obviously become much easier. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: >.< execute is the wrong word. I just want it to open the .py, not interpret it.

Comment: How about asking in the SCAR forums? http://freddy1990.com/forums/index.php/board,8.0.html

Answer (score 1):

may be this helps you:
http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs